# Scatter plot: Decreasing spacing between scatter points/x-axis ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am currently working on a 2x2 subplot figure. In each subplot, I have 3 groups on the X axis. I want to decrease the spacing between each of these groups on the X-axis. Currently, the last value on 221 subplot is very close to the first value of 222 subplot.

I have changed the spacing between subplots but I would like each of the subplots to be more compact by decreasing the spacing between the X-axis values. The variable on the X-axis is non-numeric.

Comment: I'm confused. I picture is worth a thousand words...

Answer (score 1):

Assign or use numeric values to the x axis then label the x axis ticks with the non-numeric information. Then you can play around with x-axis scaling and limits to move the *plot* around.